# Can I make Authorize.Net purchases all have to be manually accepted on VirtueMart?

Tags: joomla, authorize.net, virtuemart

I have a functioning Virtuemart cart that works with my Authorize.net account. What I need to do is make it so all the purchases must be manually accepted by me before there is a charge.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can't do this through Authorize.Net so you will need to search for Virtuemart functionality for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a setting in the payment module. Log in to Joomla and go to Virtuemart > Store > List Payment Methods > Credit Card > Configuration Tab. Look for Authentication Type and set it to AUTH_ONLY. When a user checks out, it will authorize the purchase and reserve the funds. You would then need to log in to your auth.net account and capture the funds manually in order to receive the payment.